How can i have a right side menu that opens from the left?
I need to make a side bar that has the menu icon on the right side but that opens from the left when it displays the menu.
I need something like this.

I have used drawer and endrawer but i cannot change the direction of the menu ... maybe i need a custom Drawer

In your AppBar, set the automaticallyImplyLeading to false. Then create your own drawer-button in the actions.
First, create scaffoldKey. It is needed for opening the Drawer.
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Then, your Scaffold should look like this:
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    title: const Text('Drawer Example'),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  drawer: const Drawer(
      // Your drawer content here
  ),
  body: const Center(
      // Your body content here
  ),
);

And the result is

